# Azure AD B2C session does not expire automaticaly

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have React Application which is using Azure AD B2C to authenticate users. The session configuration in the Azure portal is set to expire within 15min. But after 15 min the session does not expire at all.

My testing process:

I login using Azure AD B2C login page, after successful login the user will be redirected to homepage. Where I leave the page inactive for 15min and after that I refresh the page, instead of logout due to session inactivity. The app remain active.

Expected Behaviour:

The session should automatically expire after 15min of inactivity and should take the user to Azure login page.

Find below the configurations:

[image]